# CSS: text and button changes their order and position

Tags: html, css, position

I have a problem.

For my web project I created a background image with gradient colour and clipped it.
On this element I have some text and a button and I want everything to be centered inside the element, before the text and down of it the button.
It was working fine for a while but then my button moved before the text and both elements stays no more in the centre of the  but at the top.

Why? I am newbie with web design so I'm getting crazy, if someone can help I appreciate!
Thanks,
Ivan
Here some code:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
   }

body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 33%, hsla(224, 62%, 29%, 0.9), rgba(228, 24, 27, 0.8)), url(../Images/moscow.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 85%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 0);
}

.hero-box {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-description {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 66%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.hero-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-box">
    <h2 class="hero-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus facilis similique cupiditate temporibus excepturi, consectetur, expedita aut molestias fuga unde id nam doloremque laborum adipisci enim soluta ut nisi in!
    </h2>
    <a href="#" class="hero-btn">Visit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid` and the `place-items: center` property to put the content right in the middle of your hero `div` as follows:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hero {
  display: grid;
  /* added this */
  place-items: center;
  /* added this */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 33%, hsla(224, 62%, 29%, 0.9), rgba(228, 24, 27, 0.8)), url(../Images/moscow.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 85%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 0);
}

.hero-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-description {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 66%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.hero-btn-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}

.hero-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-box">
    <h2 class="hero-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus facilis similique cupiditate temporibus excepturi, consectetur, expedita aut molestias fuga unde id nam doloremque laborum adipisci enim soluta ut nisi in!
    </h2>
    <div class='hero-btn-container'>
      <a href="#" class="hero-btn">Visit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. I've also changed your button:hover rule to have an outline and not a border so it doesn't push up your text by 1 pixel when you hover over it.

Comment: Thaks Adam, the text and button are now in the correct position BUT, despite the "outline" option, once I hover the button my text is pushing up 1px. This did not happen before with absolute position, why?

Comment: If you see on your original code, you had the hero-btn padding as 10px and the .hero-btn:hover padding as 11px.  If you set them both to the same value (or just removed the padding property in the :hover rule, the text won't move.

Comment: I understand but what if I want my button to be 1 px bigger once I hover it? This is why I changed the padding value in :hover rule.

Comment: I'd put the button in a div of known height then you can change what you like, as long as the div height is greater than the button height. I'll amend my answer to show this.

Comment: Yes you're right Adam, now the button works properly without problems, I even didn't change the border rule into outline, thank you!